# Manually modify TOC in Lyx (Classic Thesis)

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, classicthesis, small-caps

I'm using [Miede's classic thesis](https://www.miede.de/) template for Lyx and want to change two things:

i) It uses lower case small caps for latex equivalents of \part() and \part*(). However, only \part() is shown as lower case small caps in the TOC, not \part*(). How can I change the appearance of \part*() in the TOC to lower case small caps?

ii) For visual reasons I used a protected line break ( \ \ ) in the \part*() title. Unfortunately it is also shown in the TOC. How can I renew that title in the TOC without a line break in Lyx (or Latex)?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help! It is very appreciated!

Comment: I don't think package tocloft can be used to format starred TOC entries, so some hackish way would have to be found (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41446607/ perhaps). As for the protected line break, use "short title" option (right-click on part title in LyX) and enter the same title without the line break.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @PhilipPirrip

Comment: I think that you might have to delve into the internals of `classicthesis.sty` to see/change how it treats `\part{}` and `\part*{}`. It is not obvious to me but hopefully to someone else.

Comment: @PeterWilson Me neither. But, yes, think so ... Thx!